# Insert Procedure Result Set Into Dynamic Temporary Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

How to insert the result set from a stored procedure into a dynamic temporary table other than **OPENROWSET** & **OPENQUERY** which must be capable of working in on system premises and azure SQL server databases ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it in some cases, but it might not worth the effort.

The steps are:

1. Gather the metadata of the resultset of the SP using [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql)
2. Build a custom query which creates the temp table and executes the store procedure
3. Execute the dynamic query using [`sp_execute_sql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

You'll have to build the temp table 'manually', there is no SELECT .. INTO .. FROM construct using EXEC, the destination table has to exist when you want to insert the result of an SP into a table, therefore you have to know the structure of the result set.

There is one catch: [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql) has some limitations, such as it, cannot retrieve the metadata of the first result set if the SP is using temp tables internally. A workaround is to execute the SP using the [`WITH RESULT SETS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql) clause (SQL Server 2012 and above). However if you do so, you already know the structure, so you can create the temp table too.

Comment: in my case the stored procedure may return different columns at various instances since it is purely dynamic query. So defining the result set is impossible for my case.

Comment: In this case, you stuck with `OPENROWSET` or `OPENQUERY`, I am afraid.

Comment: is there any way to find the column name,data type and ordinal position if the procedure is returning a select from a temporary table ?

Comment: Not what I know about (from outside of the SP). You can try to 'return' this information using an `OUTPUT` parameter, but this is just a wild idea.